# service postgresql stop hangs when database mounted on unresponsive filesystem - cause ha failover to hang

Tags: linux, postgresql, nfs, high-availability

I have a HA cluster (a redundant pair) set up running a postgresql database - the database is on an NFS filer. If the connection to the filer drops from the primary (eg the cables falls out) - then the primary attempts to failover. However failover hangs when running "service postgres stop" because the nfs mount isn't responsing.

My google-fu has let me down (although I would've thought somebody else would have hit this before!)

My ha.cf file:

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
logfacility local0
keepalive 2
warntime 15
deadtime 30
initdead 60
ucast eth0 <eth0 ip>
ucast eth1 <eth1 ip>
node node2
node node1
auto_failback off
respawn hacluster /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail
apiauth ipfail uid=hacluster
ping <filer IP>
```

haresource:

```
node2 IPaddr::<VIP>/24/eth0 Filesystem::<filer export>::/var/lib/pgsql::nfs::rw,noatime,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,hard,intr,noac,nfsvers=3 postgresql
```

Comment: To misquote Von Neumann, anyone who attempts to run a database against a remote filesystem is, of course, in a state of sin. I would expect that even if you find a solution to this problem, you'll only be one step closer to a bigger problem with a harder solution. Use local disks with databases.

Answer (score 1):

NFS mounts can hang for quite a while, up to ten minutes, when the server goes away.

This lag may make it very hard to properly fence the two servers.  If the NFS server comes back to life before the the postgres process dies on the failed master, the failed master's postgres process and the new master postgres process may try to simultaneously write to the database files causing corruption.